# how to `take` elements 1 through 4 of an Ruby array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have an array of objects and would like to take items 1 through 4 but `take` doesn't accept a range.

```
user.addresses.take(1...4)
```

What's a way to achieve this? In Rails so if there's some ActiveSupport addition, I could use that too.

Comment: Is `1` the first element or the second? Because array indices are zero-based.

Comment: @Stefan in this case, second.

Comment: If `addresses` is a relation and there are many entries you might want to use `user.addresses.offset(1).limit(4)` which turns that into a database query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Ruby's `take` method](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/take) accepts a single integer value for the number of elements to take. Calling `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4].take(4)` will return the 0th, 1st, 2nd, and 3rd element of the array, or `[0, 1, 2, 3]`.

If you want to skip the 0th element, you can consider [`slice`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/slice). Calling `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4].slice(1..)` will return `[1, 2, 3, 4]`. You can limit the range to take a subset. You can also use `[]` as a method on the array, as `slice` is an alias for `[]`. The infinite range syntax of `x..` was introduced in Ruby 2.6. In earlier versions of Ruby, you could accomplish this with `1..-1` instead.

Comment: Or more concisely as simply: `[0, 1, 2, 3, 4][1..]`

Comment: @ChrisDutton Yes, I'll add that. I normally prefer `slice` to be a bit more explicit and it's less confusing to people coming from a non-Ruby background.

Comment: For a more descriptive approach there's also `ary.drop(1).take(4)` but most of the time you'll see `ary[1, 4]` (take 4 starting at 1) or `ary[1..4]` (take elements 1 to 4) due to brevity.